# flutter:: Is it possible to change the timezone of a datetime?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to represent the time the file was saved as a string. The time in my country is 9 hours ahead of utc time. How can I change the current utc time to 9 hours faster?

```
  String _getTime({required String filePath}) {
    String fromPath = filePath.substring(
        filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, filePath.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (fromPath.startsWith("1", 0)) {
      DateTime dateTime =
      DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(fromPath));
      var dateLocal = dateTime.toLocal();
      print(dateLocal);
      print(dateTime);
      int year = dateLocal.year;
      int month = dateLocal.month;
      int day = dateLocal.day;
      int hour = dateLocal.hour;
      int min = dateLocal.minute;
      String dato = '$year-$month-$day--$hour:$min';
      return dato;
    } else {
      return "No Date";
    }
  }
```

Comment: A `DateTime` object either must be in UTC or in the local time zone.  If you want anything else,  use `package:timezone` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package ---->>>>> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone

Add the package dependencies to your project, import the package into the file you're working in and write the code below to get your currenTimeZone

final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
debugPrint(currentTimeZone);